# Need to prove $\frac{3}{5}(2^{\frac{1}{3}}-1)\le\int_0^1\frac{x^4}{(1+x^6)^{\frac{2}{3}}}dx\le1$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

I need to show that 
$$\frac{3}{5}(2^{\frac{1}{3}}-1)\le\int_0^1\frac{x^4}{(1+x^6)^{\frac{2}{3}}}dx\le1$$
I just know that if in $[a,b]$, $f(x)\le g(x)\le h(x)$, then
$$\int_a^bf(x)dx\le\int_a^bg(x)dx\le\int_a^bh(x)dx$$
How do I get a function like $f$ and $h$ in the range $[0,1]$, for the function $g(x)=\frac{x^4}{(1+x^6)^{\frac{2}{3}}}$? I mean, is there an approach without solving backwards?

Comment: maybe say ${3\over 5}(x+1)^{1\over 3}$ and differentiate it, then put it into the integral from 0 to 1, so you get the left hand side, do the same for 1.

Comment: for that matter, what about considering $\frac{3}{5}(x^n+1)^{\frac{1}{3}}$? Because for any $n$, the $LHS$ is verified. Why should I choose $n=1$?

Comment: I guess it can work too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider left part first. You need to get integral there, something like $f(1)-f(0)$
$$
\frac 35 \left ( 2^{\frac 13}-1\right ) = \frac 35 \left ( (1+\fbox 1)^{\frac 13}-(1+\fbox 0)^{\frac 13}\right ) =\frac 35 \left . \left ( 1+x^n\right )^{\frac 13} \right |_0^1
$$
Now, you can imagine that values inside of the boxes are values of almost any power of $x$, since $$1^n = 1 \\
0^n = 0$$
So $f(x) = \frac 35 \left (1+x^n \right )^{\frac 13}$, and therefore $f'(x) = \frac n5 \left ( 1+x^n\right )^{-\frac 23}x^{n-1}$

To choose which power should be there, just pay attention to the integral given. It has $x^4$ in enumerator, and $(1+x^6)$ in denominator, so power could be either 5 (to match enumerator after differentiating) or 6 (to match denominator).
$$
n = 5 \\
f(x) = \frac 35 \left (1+x^5 \right )^{\frac 13} \\
f'(x) = \frac {x^4}{\left ( 1+x^5\right)^{\frac 23}}
$$
Now, all you have to prove is
$$
\frac{x^4}{\left (1+x^5 \right)^{\frac 23}} \le \frac {x^4}{\left (1+x^6 \right)^{\frac 23}},\quad \text{for}\ \forall x \in [0,1]
$$
which is equivalent to 
$$
1 + x^6 \le 1 + x^5
$$
or
$$
x \le 1
$$
which is true.

If you  choose to match denominator
$$
n = 6 \\
f(x) = \frac 35 \left ( 1+x^6\right )^{\frac 13} \\
f'(x) = \frac 65 \left ( 1+x^6\right)^{-\frac 23} x^5
$$
You have to prove that
$$
\frac {6 x^5}{5\left ( 1+x^6\right)^{\frac 23}} \le \frac {x^4}{\left (1+x^6 \right)^{\frac 23}},\quad \text{for}\ \forall x \in [0,1]
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
6x \le 5
$$
which is not true for all $x \in [0,1]$, so it's better to stick with $n = 5$.

Right part is easier, I can put some notes if it's necessary.

Comment: that explains what I required!

Answer (score 1):

Try $\dfrac{x^4}{(1+x^5)^{2/3}}$

Comment: please elaborate, on which side of the inequality do I try this on?

Comment: left. For the right, you just use 1.

Comment: You can integrate it by substitution $u=x^5$

Comment: I'm sorry, but the integration gives me $\frac{9}{25}$ instead of $\frac{3}{5}$. Should I go for the integration without $\frac{3}{5}$? I believe that gives the answer.

Comment: Yes! You are right!@AshishGaurav I made a mistake on the computing. Sorry about that. I have seen it has been modified. Thanks.